# what's issue? I cannot use this ways. Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. Try removing the extra arguments

Tags: flutter

what's issue? I cannot use this ways.

Error Code `Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found. Try removing the extra arguments.`

In stat_managerment.dart, I used this method.

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
final userLogged = StateProvider((ref) => FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser);
```

And, in the main.dart, I tried to call processLogin function, but I got the error.

```
import 'package:barber_booking/state/state_managerment.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth_ui/firebase_auth_ui.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth_ui/providers.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_riverpod/flutter_riverpod.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
processLogin(BuildContext context) {
    var user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
    if (user == null) {
      FirebaseAuthUi.instance()
          .launchAuth([AuthProvider.phone()]).then((firebaseUser) {
        context.read(userLogged).state = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
      });
    } else {}
  }
```

Comment: Can you include about the package  you are  using

Comment: @YeasinSheikh sorry, I don't your mean.. main.dart or stat_managerment.dart? I'd updated my context

Comment: Sorry not getting any issue, also you might upgrade your package

Comment: Why you are using context read to access riverpod?

Answer (score 0):

```
context.read(userLogged).state = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```

change to this

```
context.read<YourStateProviderClass>().state = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
```